# Click event for attach files link is not being bound in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

So far uploading works in Chrome on Linux, OSX and windows, and IE on Windows, but fails in Firefox for all OS's.

The issue seems to be that no event is being bound to the attach file link which can be seen when using Allan Jardine's Visual Event plugin.

However in the online demo http://plupload.com/example_custom.php, an event bound to the click event can be seen using the plugin.

Any idea why firefox is failing in this case?

```
<form action="/notes" class="new_note" data-remote="true" id="new_note" method="post">
  <h3>Create Note</h3>
  <textarea cols="40" id="note_content" name="note[content]" rows="1"></textarea>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id='attachments'>
        <a href="#" id="attach-files" style="display:none">Add Attachment</a>
        <a href="#" id="upload-files" style="display:none">Upload Files</a>
      </td>
      <td id='button'>
        <input class="button button-green" disabled="disabled" id="note_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Post Note" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

javascript

```
bind_plupload: function(url) {
  // plupload setup
  var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight',
    browse_button : 'attach-files',
    container : 'attachments',
    max_file_size : '2mb',
    url : url,
    multipart: true,   
    flash_swf_url : '/javascripts/plugins/plupload/plupload.flash.swf',
    silverlight_xap_url : '/javascripts/plugins/plupload/plupload.silverlight.xap',
    filters : [
      {title : "Images", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
      {title : "Documents", extensions : "pdf,doc,docx,odt,txt,xls"}
    ]
  });

  // push files to server after file is selected
  if ($.browser.msie) {
    $("#upload-files").show().click(function() {
      uploader.start();
      return false;
    });
  }
  else {
    $("#upload-files").remove()
    $(":file").live("change", function(e) {
      uploader.start();
    });
  }

  uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
    $.each(files, function(i, file) {
      var msg = sprintf("<div id=\"%s\">%s <b></b></div>", file.id, file.name);
      $('#attachments').append(msg);
    });
    up.refresh(); // Reposition Flash/Silverlight
  });

  uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function(up, file) {
    $('#' + file.id + " b").html(file.percent + "%");
  });

  uploader.bind('Error', function(up, err) {
    var msg = sprintf("<div>%s%s</div>", err.message, (err.file ? " "+err.file.name : ""))
    $('#attachments').append(msg);
    up.refresh(); // Reposition Flash/Silverlight
  });

  uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file) {
    $('#' + file.id + " b").html("100%");
  });

  uploader.init();
} // bind plupload
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox when the 'attachments' id was moved from the  element to a newly nested  tag things worked.

```
<td>
    <div id='attachments'>
        <a href="#" id="attach-files" style="display:none">Add Attachment</a>
        <a href="#" id="upload-files" style="display:none">Upload Files</a>
    </div>
</td>
```

I think this would be considered a bug.

Answer (score 0):

<s>IDs are not supposed to contain hyphens.</s>

Try taking changing the IDs to `attach_files`, `upload_files`, etc. and see if it works.

Nevermind.  (See comments.)

Comment: I am not so sure about that. Although since I have spent way to long trying to get this to work I gave it a go anyway and it didn't work. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Comment: Right you are.  This came up in a project a couple of years ago, and some reference (wish I could find it!) told me that IDs could **only** contain alphanumerics and underscores.  My guess is that it's a throwback to the bad old days of `document.idname`, where a hyphenated idname would obviously not work.